# PHP - How to refactor code so that I don't have to copy and paste it for each form instance?

Tags: php, wordpress

Not sure what kind of refactoring this is called or if there's a name for it. But I'm looking to see how I can take this snippet of code and reformat it to be 'dynamic'?

For example, we have a site that hosts 8-10 properties with a contact form for each property. I hate to create 16 new lines for each property and if more are added the file will just keep getting larger.

```
add_filter( 'gform_after_submission_x', 'set_post_content', 10, 3 ); //x to be replaced with form ID
function set_post_content( $entry, $form ) {
$post_url = 'https://abc.infusionsoft.com/app/form/process/xyz'; //xyz is unique to the form created in infusionsoft
$fields = array(
    'inf_field_FirstName'=> rgar( $entry, 'a' ),//a can vary depending on the field ID for firstname
    'inf_field_LastName'=> rgar( $entry, 'b' ),//b can vary depending on the field ID for lastname
    'inf_field_Email'=> rgar( $entry, 'c' ),//c can vary depending on the field ID for email
    'inf_form_xid' => 'xyz',//matches the unique ID in the $post_url string
    'infusionsoft_version' => '1.70.0.77019',
    'inf_form_name' => 'Web Form submitted'
  );
GFCommon::log_debug( 'gform_confirmation: body => ' . print_r( $fields, true ) );
$request  = new WP_Http();
$response = $request->post( $post_url, array( 'body' => $fields ) );
GFCommon::log_debug( 'gform_confirmation: response => ' . print_r( $response, true ) );
}
```

I'm hoping my comments make sense. Essentially the variables for example purposes only: x, xyz, a, b and c need to be dynamic in a way that when a form is submitted this variables can be filled in so that the data can be sent to Infusionsoft.

Answer (score 0):

If your property forms have a naming convention like "[Property name] property contact form" then you can create use the hook **gform_after_submission** to process any form that is submitted. Then, you can just run a quick check to ensure its one of the property contact forms and then process every form with a single function.

If each form has a unique post url you can add the **xyz** variable to a hidden field in the gravity form itself then append it to a string variable in the function

```
add_action( 'gform_after_submission', 'set_post_content', 10, 2 );

function set_post_content( $entry, $form ) {
        //logic to check that its a form for one of the properties
        if(strpos($form['title'], 'property contact form(or whatever the naming 
               convention is') == false){
                  return false;
         }   

      $post_url = 'https://abc.infusionsoft.com/app/form/process/' . rgar( $entry, 'xyz' ) ;
    //the rest of the logic for the form 
}
```

Comment: Quick question on the if statement, if it does return false then everything below that seizes to execute?

Comment: @Jose Yes, if it returns false the function stops there.